# BI/B2 Visa status covid-19

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I have a Tourist Visa and got accepted to enter the USA for a vacation, March 10. I understand that I get 6 months to stay, but my flights have been cancelled 4 times, so I assume that my last day is September 10. My consulate here in the USA told me the country might open August 15th. I have a flight scheduled for August 18th. I'm really not sure if this will be possible.

I don't intend to stay for an extra 6 months; I think that if it's not August it would be September 15th. So what should I do? Applying online has been very difficult for me. I always go back to basics. I think 1 or 2 months would be enough, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Don't assume. Open your passport and look at the expiration date on the visa itself. What is it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: The expiration date of a US visa is irrelevant to how long a person can stay inside the US.

Comment: @user102008 I am well aware of that. That is not the point: You first have to know the expiration date of the visa!

Comment: @MichaelHampton: From reading the question, it seems the OP is already in the US, and is delayed on leaving the US. If this is the case, the visa is irrelevant since the OP is already in the US.

Comment: @user102008 I read it as the OP has not yet visited the USA. Apparently so did Doc who posted the answer below. I guess we could both be wrong. Hopefully the OP will come back and clarify.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I also read it as saying that Carlos F was asking about when he could visit the US, but prompted by user102008's comments, I looked at it with the other interpretation in mind, and everything about it makes much more sense in that light.

Comment: If he is already in the US, he can just check his admission stamp in his passport or his online I-94.

Comment: OP explicitly says "here in the USA", so that IMHO makes it fairly clear they're already there and looking for a flight back home.

Answer (score 9):

US Visas are a little different to those from many other countries.

You must enter the country before the expiry date on your visa - which is likely at least 1 year after the visa was issued (possibly 5 years or more).

When you enter the country you will be given a time period that you can stay for, which is generally 6 months from the date that you enter. This time is not related to the date on which your visa was issued, or even when it expires (ie, you can stay in the US after visa expiry - as long as you entered the country whilst it was still valid)

However expecting to visit the US as a tourist in August or even September of 2020 is simply crazy.  There is ZERO chance that COVID-19 will be under control by then, and visiting puts you and others at risk.  Stay home, and re-plan your holiday for (at least) the latter half of 2021.

Comment: I think the OP means that he is already in the US and his home country has not opened borders so he is unable to return. He wants to extend his stay for only 1-2 months, and not for six months, which he needs advise with. Your answer assumes that he is not in the US.

Answer (score 9):

First, how long you were admitted for is determined by the I-94 granted to you when you entered the US. I-94s granted at entry are electronic these days, and you can look up yours at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/ . The date on your I-94 is usually also written below the entry stamp, but sometimes they forget to write it there, or write it wrong, so always check your I-94 to make sure. B2 are usually admitted for 6 months, but it can be shorter if the officer wants it to be, and even the "6 months" may be defined differently from officer to officer (sometimes it might be 180 days or something like that), so don't assume -- check to know what it is.

If you cannot leave by the date on your I-94, you need to apply for Extension of Stay by filing [form I-539](https://www.uscis.gov/i-539). You can file this online or by mail, but it needs to be received by USCIS by the date on your I-94. You can request up to 6 months of extension at a time. You can stay in the US while your I-539 is pending, even if your I-94 expires in the meantime. If you have any questions about the form you can post a new question on this site.